# Breaking text in Android's TextView

Tags: android, textview, line-breaks

I have the text string

> Lorem ipsum dolor sed do eiusmod tempor sit am.

which I would like to display on the screen. Certain phones can display the whole sentence in single line, while others are not very wide and will display the sentence like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sed do eiusmod tempor sit
>
> am.

which looks very ugly. It would be better to break it up more evenly, like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sed do eiusmod tempor sit
>
> tempor sit am.

How do I make sure that the TextView never breaks the text so that a single word takes a whole line?

Remark: API 23 introduced the `breakStrategy` attribute (see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:breakStrategy)) for `TextView`, which would solve this problem. Unfortunately, it is not supported for lower versions. Is there some work-around here?